# SSIS expression cannot convert system.boolean to system.int32

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression

When I am trying to put expression on my SSIS Variable it is giving me

> cannot convert system.boolean to system.int32

[image]

I need help

Comment: so, add your expression please...

Comment: It could be expression conversion error, add data conversion task to convert expression initially before selecting variable

Comment: @[User::RowCount]==0?"Send Email":"Do not Send Email"

Comment: Can u add Data type of [User::RowCount] in variable pane please

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign the string values "Send Email" or "Do Not Send Email" in your expression to a variable which is a **boolean** in your package.

Either change "send..." to 'true' and "do not send..." to 'false' or set the variable you are assigning it to as a string instead of a boolean.